# Writing a vector to a output file c++

Tags: c++, vector, file-io

Here I have a structure called contacts

```
 typedef struct contacts 
    {
       string name;   //{jhonathan , anderson , felicia}
       string nickName; //{jhonny  , andy , felic}
       string phoneNumber; // {13453514 ,148039 , 328490}
       string carrier;  // {atandt , coolmobiles , atandt }
       string address; // {1bcd , gfhs ,jhtd }
    
    } contactDetails;
    
    vector <contactDetails> proContactFile;
```

I'm trying to write the data inside my vector to a output file.For this i've written the following code

```
ofstream output_file("temp.csv");
int selectContact;
cout << "Which Contact you want to delete ? Enter the relevent index " << endl;
cin >> selectContact;

if (selectContact > proContactFile.size()) {
    cout << "Invalid entry";
}
else {
    proContactFile.erase(proContactFile.begin() + (selectContact - 1));
    cout << "Delete successfully";
}
  
  ostream_iterator<contactDetails> output_iterator(output_file, "\n");
  copy(begin(proContactFile),end(proContactFile), output_iterator);  
}
output_file.close();
fin.close();
remove("Contact.csv");//Deletes contacts.csv file
rename("temp.csv" , "Contact.csv");
```

But this code always gives me an error.Also I want to write the data to the file with the following way.

`Name,Nick name,Phone number,Carrier,Address`

Whats wrong with my code?(basically what i'm doing here is let user to delete a element in the vector and the write that updated vector to a output file)

This is the error I am receiving: `Error    C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Comment: The implication here is that you have successfully written your data to the file in another part of your code. So what's the difference between this code and and the good code, or why can't you use the good code here instead of the above?

Comment: Don't make us guess, say what the error is. I have an idea but it would be nice for you to confirm it.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `ofstream output_file` has been declared twice... is that a typo?

Comment: @john i'm really sorry.The error i'm getting is 
`Error C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Oh noted

Comment: @GenoC Error that I've mentioned in the above comment |^

Comment: You need to overload operator<< for contactdetails struct

Comment: @GenoC Yeah nothing is wrong with headers

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 Hey I've no idea how to do it.Cuz i've already tried many things with this?Could you show me with an example

Comment: Consider using either [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) or textual formats like [JSON](http://json.org/). If you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with all warnings and debug info  `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. **Read a [good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html)** and [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: Comments can disappear at any time. Important information like the exact error message should be edited into the question, preferably with a [mre] that removes noise and focuses on just the lines that cause the error.

Answer (score 1):

So using this technique of writing a vector

```
ostream_iterator<contactDetails> output_iterator(output_file, "\n");
copy(begin(proContactFile),end(proContactFile), output_iterator);
```

requires that you overload `operator<<` for your struct. I.e.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const contactDetails& details)
{
    // your output code here, e.g.
    out<< details.name << ',' << details.nickName << ','; //etc << ...
    return out;
}
```

But the puzzling issue remains. The code above is for updating a file. Which implies that you already have a file. Which implies that you are already successfully writing that file somewhere else in your code. How did you achieve that?

However you managed it you should update that other code so that it uses the `operator<<` that you are going to write to fix this code. That way all your contact details output goes through one function.

Comment: I tried this thing mate.But it still says `expected a ';'`.But nothing is  missing

Comment: It still says `expected a ';'` pal

Comment: @SeektheFreak2 I can't diagnose what's wrong with your code unless I can see it.